# Multiple Random Selections Using Union- erroring

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I'm trying to get to a random 31,500 from one segmentation group and another random 31,500 from another segmentation group (and so on) in SFMC automation studio using SQL. I know I could create multiple SQL steps for each group but I'm sure it would be more effective to use unions in one single step. When I use the below logic, it validates fine but when I go to finalise the SQL step, it says "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'union'". It appears to be only due to the random sample element of the query because, without that, it saves/closes without issue.

Firstly, am I getting to my random samples in the correct way? I tried rand(31500) and it only brought back one record. Secondly, why is the below erroring?

```
    select top 31500 Contact_Key
            , c.Account_Number
            , c.Email
    from contact c
    inner join [StartingPot] m
    on c.account_number = m.account_number
    where c.CVP_Current = '1_Segment'
    order by rand()
    
    union
    select top 31500 Contact_Key
            , c.Account_Number
            , c.Email
    from contact c
    inner join [StartingPot] m
    on c.account_number = m.account_number
    where c.CVP_Current = '2_Segment'
    order by rand()
```

Comment: Are you sure that the contacts are different? Maybe you want to have UNION ALL and not Union. Another thing i would not do and is most likely to throw errors: Ambigous names for your variables since you have given the same alias twice to the same table. idk if rand works for t-sql maybe you need to go with NEWID() instead of it. If you use UNION without ALL you will most likely end up with less than 73000 because the duplicates you will have wont show up twice.

Comment: The contacts are definitely different so there shouldn't be duplicates across the segments. Union All is giving the same error (and the "all" isn't turning blue in the query so I don't think it's being processed as a function). I'm not familiar with NEWID(), what would I use that for? Thank you

Comment: I know it sounds counter-intuitive, but I would separate into multiple queries just for easier debugging and to account for potential processing issues - accounting for the 30 minute timeout if server overloaded or other processing delays. Plus I have found Union and Union All to be a bit 'wonky' in SFMC Query Activities and do what I can to avoid using it.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using ORDER BY, use the following -

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Contact_Key, c.Account_Number ORDER BY c.Account_Number ASC) AS Row
```

Query -

```
select top 31500 Contact_Key
                , c.Account_Number
                , c.Email
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Contact_Key, c.Account_Number ORDER BY c.Account_Number ASC) AS Row
        from contact c
        inner join [StartingPot] m
        on c.account_number = m.account_number
        where c.CVP_Current = '1_Segment'
    
        union

        select top 31500 Contact_Key
                , c.Account_Number
                , c.Email
                , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Contact_Key, c.Account_Number ORDER BY c.Account_Number ASC) AS Row
        from contact c
        inner join [StartingPot] m
        on c.account_number = m.account_number
        where c.CVP_Current = '2_Segment'
```

Reference - [ROWNUMBER()](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

If you wrap your whole query into a subquery and give it an alias, you should be fine e.g.

```
Select a.*
From (
select top 31500 Contact_Key
            , c.Account_Number
            , c.Email
    from contact c
    inner join [StartingPot] m
    on c.account_number = m.account_number
    where c.CVP_Current = '1_Segment'
    order by rand()
    
    union
    select top 31500 Contact_Key
            , c.Account_Number
            , c.Email
    from contact c
    inner join [StartingPot] m
    on c.account_number = m.account_number
    where c.CVP_Current = '2_Segment'
    order by rand()
) a
```